# Assign a value to a variable which has =,"

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to print the line which has below value in my text file(ex: file.txt).
I have tried multiple ways but no luck. Can someone please help me the right command.

```
selector="((Source IN ('VPS','VPSLegacy')) OR (JMS_TIBCO_SENDER='rig'))"
```

Please note that i need to use entire above value to check in the file.

Comment: What do you want - a) print that line which is already (solely?) contained in `file.txt`, or b) print the line to `file.txt`?

Comment: Can you please show what you tried?

Comment: What does "print"ing content (or modifying files) have to do with the stated operation in the title of assigning a value to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to assign a literal (potentially containing quotes or other shell syntax) to a variable, even though it comes with a performance penalty, is to use a quoted heredoc:

```
content=$(cat <<'EOF'
selector="((Source IN ('VPS','VPSLegacy')) OR (JMS_TIBCO_SENDER='rig'))"
EOF
)

echo "Value is: <$content>"
```

...correctly emits as output:

```
Value is: <selector="((Source IN ('VPS','VPSLegacy')) OR (JMS_TIBCO_SENDER='rig'))">
```

Comment: Hi, I am receiving below error. I am not sure if i am using in right format. could you please validate

[tibco@auktltkr ems]$ content=$(cat << 'backup/SB02/bridges.conf'
selector="((Source IN ('VPS','VPSLegacy')) OR (JMS_TIBCO_SENDER='rig'))"
backup/SB02/bridges.conf
)
-bash: cat : command not found

Comment: `<<'EOF'` should be an *exact* string, `EOF` is the marker to use to recognize the end of the heredoc, not a name of a file or any other such thing, and the presence of quotes is important. Also, don't add spaces where my example here didn't have them. Try copying-and-pasting the code in the answer to an online interpreter like http://ideone.com/, and you'll be able to satisfy yourself that it works; and then can retest after making individual changes to figure out whether and which of those changes break anything.

Comment: Hi , Thanks command is working fine. whole value is assigned to a variable but the main issue which i am facing now is, there are 100 of lines in my file. i require particular line should result if i check with this entire string "((Source IN ('VPS','VPSLegacy')) OR (JMS_TIBCO_SENDER='rig'))" in my file.

for exmaple: in sample.txt file if i grep with this string i should get the entire line in result

Comment: line will be like this 
 

1. create bridge source=topic:VOD.UK.PR.TILIF.Request.SOAP.CUST.RiskCredMgt.CreditLimitDetermination.ProcessCreditVet.1 target=queue:VOD.UK.PR.TILIF.Request.SOAP.CUST.RiskCredMgt.CreditLimitDetermination.ProcessCreditVet.1.A selector="((Source IN ('VPS','VPSLegacy')) OR (JMS_TIBCO_SENDER='rig'))"

Comment: See https://ideone.com/IqTUaL